# Not getting value after scanning the barcode IDAutomationHC39M

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode

I am generating IDAutomationHC39M barcode but after generating and on scanning I am not getting the any of the value.

My code is

```
    public void generateBarcode(int id)
    {
        if (plBarCode != null)
        {
            string barCode = "";

            barCode = "*"+Convert.ToString(id)+"*";
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 70, 70))
            {
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
                {
                    Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 30);
                    PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                    SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                    SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                    graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);                       
                    int w = barCode.Length * 40;                    
                    Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap);                    
                    PointF oPoint = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                    SolidBrush oBrushWrite = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                    SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);         
                    oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 100);                       
                    oGraphics.DrawString("*" + barCode + "*", oFont, oBrushWrite, oPoint);

                }
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                    Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                    imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                }
                plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
            }
        }

    }
```

what is the wrong on this code.

[image]

How should I generate my code any help?

Comment: You current code would produce a bar code with *two* `*` on each side. Remove the extra `"*"` from the `oGraphics.DrawString()` function call.

Comment: Also after removing * also it is not generating

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ u mean  barCode = " ** "+Convert.ToString(id)+" ** "; like this?

Comment: No, in the line that contains `oGraphics.DrawString("*"+barCode+"*", ...);`. You already have surrounded the ID with `*`, you don't need to do it again on that line.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ yes but after remving * that is while passing barCode =Convert.ToString(id); I am not able to generate the actual barcode

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ as I was creating with string 50 it was not scanning the barcode but as I had generated the code with 14757 it is scanning properly. Is there a limit to generate the code with some proper limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the top 5 Reasons Why a Barcode Font Won't Scan ...

http://idautomation.blogspot.in/2011/07/top-5-reasons-why-barcode-font-wont.html

If you are attempting to encode a small amount of characters, it may be a good idea to be sure that your scanner is capable of scanning the minimum amount, as many are set to read a minimum of 4 characters in a barcode. On the other hand, if there are too many characters being encoded in a barcode, then it will be too large and will not scan properly. Decreasing the font size and re-scanning may solve this issue.